# create and fill columns in dataframe in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, calculated-columns

Apologies if this is basic question. I'm a novice. Any directions are much appreciated.

I have df1 as below (POSIXct) (135 rows)

```
> head(df1)
    uniqueSessionsIni   uniqueSessionsEnd
1 2015-01-05 15:00:00 2015-01-05 15:59:00
2 2015-01-05 15:00:00 2015-01-05 15:59:00
3 2015-01-05 15:00:00 2015-01-05 15:59:00
```

vector names - with names for the new 600 columns, as below.

```
> head(names)
[1] "m0p0" "m1p0" "m2p0" "m3p0" "m4p0" "m5p0"...
```

and

```
> head(allPairs)
  Var1 Var2 names
1    1    0  m1p0
2    1    1  m1p1
```

I want to populate all rows of df1, columns 4 to 603 with values based on:   vector names - with names for the new 600 columns, as below. uniqueSessionsIni Var1 + Var2.
You'll notice that Var1 corresponds to the digit after "m" in col. names, and Var2 corresponds to digit after "p" in names.

The result would be something like this (but with more columns).

```
> head(df1)
    uniqueSessionsIni   uniqueSessionsEnd           m1p0                 m1p1    
1 2015-01-05 15:00:00 2015-01-05 15:59:00   2015-01-05 15:01:00  2015-01-05 15:02:00
2 2015-01-05 16:00:00 2015-01-05 15:59:00   2015-01-05 16:01:00  2015-01-05 16:02:00
3 2015-01-05 17:00:00 2015-01-05 15:59:00   2015-01-05 17:01:00  2015-01-05 17:02:00
```

I've tried the following code to create the new columns in df1:

```
df1[,names] <- NA
```

This successfully creates the new columns and populates with NA

So I'm trying to create a condition with a for loop to populate these new columns (3 to 603), with the code

```
df1[,names] <- for (i in df1$timestamps)
df1$uniqueSessionsIni + (as.posix(allPairs$Var1) + (as.posix(allPairs$Var2)
```

But R responds as if the expression is incomplete (+).
Is this a matter of a syntax mistake? Or I need another solution altogether to populate the new columns?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not clear. It seems like you only need one column the way you say it.  You need to make your example reproducible i.e. provide some real data and show us what you want the output to be (for less columns than 603)

Comment: In R creating and filling a data.frame column usually should be one step. Also, R is case sensitive and parentheses must match. Study the documentation of functions you want to use and take advantage of vectoriziation (using `for` loops should be an exception in your daily work).

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I've edited as suggested by @LyzandeR.

Comment: Roland, Thank you for the tips. I have read the documentation, just couldn't figure it out yet. You suggest that I try to create and populate the columns in one action. Thats is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Var2 is 0 for the first row. Is this a typo? Why is `2015-01-05 15:01:00` not `2015-01-05 15:00:00`? Does the `allPairs` data.frame have 135rows as well? This is easy to do, but I think the output does not reflect your data. Also, provide one more row to the allPairs data.frame to be able to work with your 3 rows.

Comment: @LyzandeR, thank you for bearing with me. Var2 for first row is 0, not a typo. allPairs has 600 rows, these are what I want to add as columns. I want to use the values in the column "names" as the names for the columns on table df1. Plus, fill in each row of df1 (cols 4 to 603) by summing the values of Var1 and Var2 to the minutes of  uniqueSessionsIni. BTW, df allPairs is a "list"of all possible pairs of combinations between two other vectors 60X10. Hence the difficulty in picking an illustrative sample in just a few rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(uniqueSessionsIni=as.POSIXlt(c('2015-01-05 15:00:00','2015-01-05 16:00:00', '2015-01-05 17:00:00 ')),
                  uniqueSessionsIni=as.POSIXlt(c('2015-01-05 15:59:00','2015-01-05 16:59:00', '2015-01-05 17:59:00 ')))

#note that the names column below should be of character class and not factor
allPairs <- data.frame(Var1=c(1,1), Var2=c(0,1), names=c('m1p0','m1p1'),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Solution:

```
#the list below creates the columns you need
mylist <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(allPairs)){
  mylist[[allPairs[i, 3]]] <- df1$uniqueSessionsIni + 60*as.numeric(allPairs[i, 1]) + 60*as.numeric(allPairs[i, 2])
}

> mylist
$m1p0
[1] "2015-01-05 15:01:00 GMT" "2015-01-05 16:01:00 GMT" "2015-01-05 17:01:00 GMT"

$m1p1
[1] "2015-01-05 15:02:00 GMT" "2015-01-05 16:02:00 GMT" "2015-01-05 17:02:00 GMT"
#cbind all df1 and the new column from the loop
cbind(df1, data.frame(mylist))
```

Output:

```
> cbind(df1, data.frame(mylist))
    uniqueSessionsIni uniqueSessionsIni.1                m1p0                m1p1
1 2015-01-05 15:00:00 2015-01-05 15:59:00 2015-01-05 15:01:00 2015-01-05 15:02:00
2 2015-01-05 16:00:00 2015-01-05 16:59:00 2015-01-05 16:01:00 2015-01-05 16:02:00
3 2015-01-05 17:00:00 2015-01-05 17:59:00 2015-01-05 17:01:00 2015-01-05 17:02:00
```

Comment: You are welcome :). I had made a small mistake, creating the wrong data. I fixed it now. Happy to have helped :) !!